# sklearn - How to create a sequential pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-imputation, pipelines

**Update:** The examples in this post were updated

I am reposting this question here after not getting a clear answer in a [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475704/sklearn-columntransformer-duplicate-columns-in-transformers)

I am looking for a help building a data preprocessing pipleline using sklearn's ColumnTransformer functions where the some features are preprocesses sequentially. I am well aware of how to build separate pipelines for different subsets of features. For example, my pipleline may look something like this:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer 
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer

ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                  transformers=[
                              ('num_impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), ['feat_1', 'feat_2'])
                                ('Std', StandardScaler(), ['feat_3', 'feat_4']),
                                ('Norm', Normalizer(), ['feat_5', 'feat_6']),
                                ])
```

Notice that each transformer is provided a unique set of features.

The issue I am encountering is how to apply sequential processing for the same features (different combinations of transformations and features). For example,

```
ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                  transformers=[
                              ('num_impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), ['feat_1', 'feat_2', , 'feat_5'])
                              ('Std', StandardScaler(), ['feat_1', 'feat_2','feat_3', 'feat_4', 'feat_6']),
                              ('Norm', Normalizer(), ['feat_1', 'feat_6'])

                                ])
```

Notice that feat_1 was provided to three transformations, feat_2 was provided to two transformers (impute and Std), and feat_6 was provided to two transformers (Std and Norm)

A pipeline like this will two duplicate columns for feat_2 and feat_3, and three duplicate columns for feat_1. Building a separate pipeline for each transformation/feature combination is not scalable.

Comment: You want a sequential pipeline, so use Pipeline:  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html

Comment: This will not resolve the issue. A Pipeline like this Pipeline(steps=[('PreProc', ColumnTransformer(....)), ('model', SVC())]) will still have the same issue. Can you please provide an example.

Comment: Can you list for each feature what operation you want to appy? eg: feat_1: SimpleImputer, StandardScaler; feats_2: SimpleImputer; etc. ?

Comment: feat_1: SimpleImputer and StandardScaler; feat_2: SimpleImputer and StandardScaler; feat_3: StandardScaler;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to do sequential transformations, you should use `Pipeline`.

```py
imp_std = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
        ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ]
)

ColumnTransformer(
    remainder='passthrough',
    transformers=[
        ('imp_std', imp_std, ['feat_1', 'feat_2']),
        ('std', StandardScaler(), ['feat_3']),
    ]
)
```

or

```py
imp = ColumnTransformer(
    remainder='passthrough',
    transformers=[
        ('imp', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), ['feat_1', 'feat_2']),
    ]
)

Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('imp', imp),
        ('std', StandardScaler()),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Ben, As I indicated in my comment to Julio, this solution is not scalable and will require me to build separate pipelines for each combination of preprocessing steps and features. I will update the original question to reflect the possible complexity

Comment: As Julio says, most commonly you won't have very many distinct pipelines and so the first approach above works reasonably well.  If you have many different pipelines that overlap quite a bit, you could have a "master" pipeline that you slice down; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62234209/10495893.

Comment: The link you provided was indeed helpful. As you indicated in answer, the assumption is that last transformation operates on the entire frame, otherwise, it will fail. A good solution is to find the new order on columns between each pipeline steps and update the indices. Is this possible?

Comment: Not programmatically, I think.  If your steps don't mess with the columns much, then you can do it by hand.  Imputing and scaling, e.g., preserve column order, and a columntransformer puts the results in order of the transformations (remainder last).  But if you one-hot encode (so now the number of columns is data-dependent), you'll have a very hard time.

Comment: This is makes sense. That is why my questions was about a scalable (aka programmatic) approach. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Now that sklearn has added support for dataframes-out, you can use the (possibly slightly modified) column names even later in a pipeline, so the order of columns isn't necessarily needed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by creating separate preprocessing steps for each data type, the most common case is you have categorical and continuous variables

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector as selector
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

cont_prepro = Pipeline([("imputer",SimpleImputer(strategy = "median")),("scaler",StandarScaler())])

cat_prepro = Pipeline([("imputer",SimpleImputer(strategy = "most_frequent")),("encoder",OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = "ignore"))])

preprocessing = make_column_transformer((cont_prepro,selector(dtype_exclude = "object")),(cat_prepro,selector(dtype_include = "object"))

pipe = Pipeline([("preprocessing",preprocessing),("model",LogisticRegression())])
```

If you want to separate features on each step by listing instead of by type you should create a list with the specific columns as you already did in your example and remove the selector part.

In your case:

```
pipe_one = Pipeline([("num_impute",SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),('Std', StandardScaler())])

preprocessing = make_column_transformer((pipe_one,["feat_1","feat_2"]),remainder='passthrough')

pipe = Pipeline([("preprocessing",preprocessing),("model",LogisticRegression())])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this solution is not scalable and will require me to build separate pipelines for each combination of preprocessing steps and features. I was hoping to find a solution where a series of preprocessing steps take place sequentially and for each step a separate sublist of features is provided. This way, given a random feature the transformation step n will be applied on top of transformation step n-1 for this feature